# How to fill image up to three column section in Sharepoint site

Tags: image, sharepoint

I know Hero content can let image to fill up all container.But Hero content 3 tiles, are not even

[image]

However, Three columns section can not let images to fill up width of each column. Then if image has different size, hard to uniform the size.

Anyone know a solutions? Thanks a lot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For SharePoint Modern pages, we can only use the built-in layouts. For your question, I will suggest you to use [Image gallery web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-image-gallery-web-part-bbcbe560-14a7-4369-8ef5-3255845e3bfd) to display your images.

How it looks:
[image]